# MongoDB/Mongoid Ruby - How to update multiple documents field with different values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using Ruby on Rails and I have the following Mongo collection,

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "Jackie Chan",
  sn: "ABC123",
  Country: Australia
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: "Brad Pitt",
  sn: "ABC124",
  Country: Russia
},
{
  _id: 3,
  name: "Al Pacino",
  sn: "ABC125",
  Country: USA
}
```

I have another MYSQL table called `Device`, which also has Country and `device_sn` field. I want to find the MondoDB document using `device_sn` and update the value of  mongoDB `country` field from `Device` table. I want to update the country field of each document to a different values received from another MYSQL table.

```
[#<Device:0x00007f9adb7df898 device_sn: "ABC123", country: "US">, 
 #<Device:0x00007f9adb7df668 device_sn: "ABC124", country: "CA">,
 #<Device:0x00007f9adb7df370 device_sn: "ABC125", country: "AU">]
```

I know how to update the multiple document with the same value, but here the case is each document should be updated with different values of `country` field.  I know how to perform it using looping and updating, but I want to know is there a bulk update or updateMany query available to perform this type of operation.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know is there a bulk update or updateMany query available to perform this type of operation.

There is no way to perform that otherwise than by using looping.

Comment: But there _are_ bulk updates which could prevent looping network round trips to the MongoDB database and should be utilized, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb bulkwrite method. This method takes array of write operations. This is much better then simply looping the data and updating the database. As it will reduce your network calls drastically.

In your case you have to create multiple objects of updateOne or updateMany by iterating your data. Please refer to [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#std-label-bulkwrite-write-operations-updateOneMany) documentation of mongodb to know more.

Ruby mongo driver [implementation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ruby-driver/master/api/Mongo/BulkWrite.html) for same.

```
Mongo::BulkWrite.new(
  collection,
  [
    
    { update_one: { filter: { sn: device_sn_id_1 }, update: { '$set' => { Country: 'device_sn_id_1_country' }}}},
    { update_one: { filter: { sn: device_sn_id_2 }, update: { '$set' => { Country: 'device_sn_id_2_country' }}}},
    ...
    
  ]
)
```